# Javascript,jquery Countdown

Tags: javascript

I made a countdown timer like this  and what I want to do is after the time is finish to change an element from my page like an example "price" to change,can you help me guys?
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVxRvw)!

```
var clock1 = document.getElementById("midnight-countdown")
, tdy = new Date();
clock1.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate() + 1) ).toString();
setInterval(function(){
clock1.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate() + 1) ).toString();
}, 1000);


<h4 id="midnight-countdown"></h4>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [ask] for information on how to ask good questions on this site.  In general, it's better to post some code that you have tried that doesn't work as it shows you have put some effort into solving the problem yourself, as SO is not a coding service but a QA site.

Comment: can you please be more clear of how exactly you want it to work

Comment: Yeah i want to make a countdown timer and when is done to change my price of products but i need this without reset when customer refresh the page.Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the counter function returns empty string if the number for hour/min/second is 0.

It means that when the moment comes that innerHtml would be empty, so you can put a check in your interval to catch it and do whatever you want:

```
setInterval(function(){
        clock1.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate() + 1) ).toString();
        if(!clock1.innerHTML) {
            //do change the UI however you like
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it by creating the countdown as an object, and using the object parameters to identify when the countdown has ended.

```
var countdownTimer = {
    time : 30,
    reset: function() {
        this.time = 30;
        $('.timer').html('<h3>' + this.time + ' seconds remaining</h3>');
    },
    start: function() {
        counter = setInterval(countdownTimer.count, 1000);  
    },
    stop: function() {
        clearInterval(counter);
    },
    count: function() {
            countdownTimer.time--;
            console.log(countdownTimer.time);
            $('.timer').html(countdownTimer.time);
        if (countdownTimer.time >= 0) {
            $('.timer').html('<h3>' + countdownTimer.time + ' seconds remaining</h3>');
        }
        else {
            countdownTimer.reset();
            (insert code here to inject your price change)
        }
    }
}
```

In this situation, when countdownTimer.time is below 0, the counter is reset and you can then add the necessary logic to change your element.

Comment: Thanks very much but i don't want when the page got refresh to reset countdown :( thanks guys!

Comment: Hey Jeff can you put also and mark-up for html for this solution? i can`t make it to print something! Thanks!

Comment: Does, this requires jQuery to function.  Include that library in addition to your JS script.